# Running a for loop for plotting geographical information

Tags: r

I am trying to plot points on a map for a data set by the year the data points are from.

I want to do this in a for loop where

```
points( x=longitude, y=latitude)
```

I ran a nested loop

```
for ( i in xvector) {
    for (g in yvector){
        #Plot commands
        points( x = i , y = g)
    }
}
```

I made 2 vectors containing data for each year range (there are four ranges) based on latitude and longitude. One vector for latitude, one for longitude points. How would I go about creating a loop that would plot the entire year range for x and y points, creating 4 different plots?

I can run this without a loop but that is a bit inefficient.

Comment: What's the point of the `for` loop here? Why not `points(xvector, yvector)` without looping?

Comment: This would be a much clearer question if you shared a little bit of sample data. You have 2 vectors with latitude and longitude, okay. How are your years defined? Is it a fixed number of point per year, or is there a vector of years?

Comment: @GregorThomas In my thinking, the point is because I want to run it 4 times to produce 4different plots. There are 2 vectors, each containing 4-year ranges. One vector for longitude points in 4 date ranges and the same for latitude. I can run the code 4 times to get the info I need but that seems inefficient and was wondering if I could pull the info into a loop.

Comment: Can you please share a sample of data? `dput(xvector[1:10])` will give a copy/pasteable version of the first ten entries of `xvector`, ditto for `yvector`. Pick a suitable subset to illustrate the problem.